# Paypal delayed chained payments execution detailed execution procedure in .net

Tags: c#, .net, paypal-adaptive-payments

I was searched so many sites but I am not able to get any example for executing `Paypal` delayed chain payments.

Any one can help please? Thanks in advance.

Comment: How about this: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/adaptive-payments/ht_ap-delayedChainedPayment-curl-etc/?mark=delayed%20chain

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Yaron Thanks for your suggestion. i have looked into the that url.